# Check if an object IN a list with the same VALUE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python list of some complex objects, and a target object which I wish to check of its occurrence in the list **by value**.

In other words, I need to find if any of the objects in the list, has the same attributes with the same values as the target object.

I tried:

```
if node in nodes:
```

But this compares the references of the objects not the values.

I know I can do some nested loops to check every single attribute, but I am looking for a smarter way, if any.

Comment: What kind of objects are being collected and checked, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you modify the `Node` class (e.g. add a method)?

Comment: @G.Anderson The objects are instances of a Node class that has multiple attributes, many of them are instances of other classes themselves, some attributes are lists and sets, and few are primitive types.

Comment: @slider Yes, I have access to it

Comment: Is `__eq__` defined on these classes you're comparing to?

Comment: If there is a defined `repr` method defined for your objects, it might be possible to use that: `repr(1) in repr([1,2,3,4,5])` returns `True`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `Node` class's [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method to compare interesting properties with other nodes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val1 == other.val1 and self.val2 == other.val2


nodes = [Node(1, 2), Node(3, 4), Node(5, 6)]
node = Node(1, 2)
print(node in nodes) # True
```

If you don't want to write an `__eq__` method for fear of breaking old behavior, you can perhaps write a custom equality method that only checks certain properties and then use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). For example:

```
def val1s_equal(n1, n2):
    return n1.val1 == n2.val1

if any(val1s_equal(node, n) for n in nodes):
    print('do something')
```

Comment: Note that this will have ramifications if you are using `Node` instances in some of the other built-in containers (e.g. as `dict` keys)

Comment: Will this affect the the way I use `node in nodes` normally before?

Comment: @AhmedHammad can you define "normally". Is that when it was just comparing references? If yes, then in addition to getting `True` for the same reference, you will also get `True` if you have another object with the same properties.

Comment: Very good! However, hard coding the value comparisons would take hundreds of lines because of the complexity of the Node. If there is a guarantee that there is no way of comparing the values dynamically somehow, I will definitely go with this.